# Generating random number from 0 to 10 including both

Tags: actionscript-3

I heard of some `Math.random()` but I'm not sure about using it correctly. Number must be whole, so I suppose I'll need some rounding function.

Comment: Check this tutorial: [AS3 Math.random()](http://www.untoldentertainment.com/blog/2008/03/23/as3-tutorial-mathrandom/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Math.random() returns a number between 0 - 1. Multiply it with 10 an round it using an int.

```
// random number between 1- 10
var randomRounded : int = Math.round(Math.random() * 10);
```

Edit: more accurate version

```
// more accurate
var randomRounded : int = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
```

Comment: Mattias has it almost right.
His code however has an uneven probability distribution. All numbers from 1 to 9 have twice as much probability to be generated in comparison to 0 and 10. For instance, a 1 will be generated if the pseudo random number generator produces a 0.5, but also with 1.49999999999.
But a 0 will only be generated if the random number is between 0 and 0.4999999999
The same applies to the 10.
See my answer for the correct code.

Comment: Nice explanation :). I have not had the need to be that accurate though.

Comment: Quick correction: assigning a floating point `Number` to an `int` truncates the value - any values after the decimal point are discarded. So both 4.4 and 4.9 become 4. This is actually equivilent to `Math.floor()`, not `Math.round()`.

Answer (score 3):

Math.random produces a pseudo random number between [0;1[ (0 included, but 1 excluded)
To have an evenly distributed probability for all numbers between 0 and 10, you need to:

```
var a : int = Math.floor( Math.random() * 11 )
```

Comment: This is the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Math.round(Math.random()*10); maybe?